# I get an OAuthPermissionsException on media-like in python-instagram api. Is there any mistake in my code?

Tags: django, django-views, authorization, instagram-api

I am trying to like media and got exception:

```
(400) OAuthPermissionsException-This request requires scope=likes, but   
this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must 
re-authorize your application with scope=likes to be granted write permissions.
```

But I've authorized with the scope=likes using url for instagram:

```
url = unauthenticated_api.get_authorize_url(scope=["basic","likes","comments","relationships"])
return render(request, 'app/login.html', {'url': url})
```

Comment: I've revoked the access in profile instagram. And tried to authorize again, i see than the url is right with the scope=likes, but anyway instagram offers only basic authorization. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Starting April 14th 2015, new clients need to request access to be able to post likes, follows, and comments. For more information please read the Developer Blog at http://developers.instagram.com.